# Laplace Transform of $L^{2}$ Function.

Tags: functional-analysis, lp-spaces, integral-transforms

I know the Fourier transform is an isometry of $L^2$ functions. I've read that the Laplace Transform of an $L^2$ function is $L^2$ but cannot prove it nor can I find a proof. Does anyone know of a proof?

Comment: Look up the Plancherel theorem.